# Can you fill a shape in .dxf format?

Tags: vector, screen-printing

I hired a guy to do a layout for a printed circuit board design and I'm trying to get my graphic printed on the board's silkscreen. The designer tells me that he needs in in .dxf format.

I found a way to convert my .png graphic to a .dxf format but when he puts it on the board, it doesn't fill in (the graphic is just some simple stylized lettering). I was using a cheap converter which I noticed that some of the shapes did not close completely. I'm trying adobe illustrator now, which does a much better job of converting my image to the vector format and all of the shapes appear to be fully closed now. However, I see no property or obvious way to fill it in (mind you, I'm a complete newbie at this).

Is he going to be able to fill in the lettering on the PCB layout now that I have a vector file with closed shapes? If not, how can I get it to fill in?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by filled in, there shouldn't be any issue with something as simple as that. Just give him the vector file and he should know what to do. If not, you should really change the person you are working with...

Comment: Yeah he's basically done except for this logo. He wants to charge 3 hours at $125/hour to fill it in. Hopefully that was just because the shapes were not complete on the files I gave him. I'm not gonna work with him again.

Comment: Why dont you have your logo in a vector format to begin with? And DXF may or may not support fills depends on version. Essentially cad applications dont operate as graphic design ones.

Answer (score 1):

I work in Illustrator and I have to send some files in .dxf for a CAD program called Audaces.

The open path problem is the CAD program do not interpret the curves in a path.

If the path is rounded you must do the following:

Increase the anchor points 4 times, now you have anchors enough to do the next step;

In simplify panel check **straight lines**. This will remove all the curved segments;

Export now.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: I dont think this is correct many and most CAD applications understand beziers just fine. Some CAD's understand fills others do not. Many CAD's understand circles which illustrator does not.  So if you want to claim the CAD does not do this and that you need to be much more specific. If you sent me a file with that many anchor for me to put in my CAD (yeah i work with 6 different CAD apps every day) i would just think your an I***t and move on with my life. But yes for example KiCAD does not understand curves. By the way the printer drivers also do this behind the scenes.

Comment: Unfornutatelly, that's the only way the CAD program (Audaces) could read the .dxf file saved by Illustrator.

Comment: Thats fine but then you need to say that this applies to Audaces or some CAD's. You can not say or even suggest that this applies to CAD in general

Comment: Of course. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

.dxf file for all i know is for laser printers. the logic it can read is 0 & 1
(on or off, black or white, cut or raster) colors does not matter.
back then I just save ai files of mine as svg and it is only black and white.
the Dark and Light shades depends on the power he/she will set directly in laser cutting machine. The power will determine the depth of cuting or raster. this also apply in cutter plotter for vinyl stickers as per T-shirt printing is concerned.

[image: for example]

the black fill will only be burned and the red one will be the cutting part. He/She will set first the rasters D and little circle then next then increase the power to cut the red circle. So the D text will remain on the canvas while the circle will be cut with the red stroke as it shape.